# Unable to see my images on web hosted by Github

Tags: html

I'm facing a problem that my images (local saved images) in html file are not visible when I host my html file using Github.

I hosted many times using different methods but unable to fix it..

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? Maybe even a link to the github repo would help us debug your issue.

Comment: Looks like it is not working with relative path like /abc/xyz
Try to add the image into your repo then push it into main, then set the url
<img src="https://github.com/<your_githubname>/<repo_name>/blob/main/gif/<image-name>.jpg"

Comment: Your question could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your question is correct and are able to answer. You can find more information on how to write good questions in the help center.